# Connect to MySQL in a docker container (Vagrant on Windows/VirtualBox)

Tags: mysql, docker, vagrant, mysql-workbench, docker-container

I am trying to create a virtualised dev environment on Windows using Vagrant and Docker (as are a lot of people). The problem I have is that I cannot connect (or I dont understand how to) from MySQL Workbench running on my Windows laptop to my MySQL DB in a Docker container in Boot2Docker. This is how I visualise the connection:

MySQL Work bench -> 3306 -> Boot2Docker -> 3306 -> Docker -> MySql

However I cannot connect to the DB from MySQLWorkbench. I have tried connection to the Boot2Docker host 10.0.2.15 on 3306 and tcp over ssh using the private key of the Boot2Docker box ".vagrant\machines\dockerhost\virtualbox\id"

What am I doing wrong/what have I misunderstood.

My Vagrantfile:
    ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

```
DOCKER_HOST_NAME = "dockerhost"
DOCKER_HOST_VAGRANTFILE = "./host/Vagrantfile"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306

  config.vm.define "mysql" do |v|
    v.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "mysql"
      d.env = {
        :MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD => "root",
        :MYSQL_DATABASE     => "dockertest",
        :MYSQL_USER         => "dockertest",
        :MYSQL_PASSWORD     => "docker"
      }
      d.ports =["3306:3306"]
      d.remains_running = "true"
      d.vagrant_machine = "#{DOCKER_HOST_NAME}"
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "#{DOCKER_HOST_VAGRANTFILE}"
    end
  end
end
```

My hosts/Vagrantfile (describing my Boot2docker host) is:

```
FORWARD_DOCKER_PORTS='true'
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|


  config.vm.provision "docker"

  # The following line terminates all ssh connections. Therefore
  # Vagrant will be forced to reconnect.
  # That's a workaround to have the docker command in the PATH

  #Clear any existing ssh connections
  ####NOTE: ps aux seems to give variable results depending on run -> process number can be ####first #or second causing provision to fail!!!
  config.vm.provision "clear-ssh", type: "shell", inline:
        "ps aux | grep 'sshd:' | awk '{print $1}'  | xargs kill"
#        "ps aux | grep 'sshd:' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill"


  config.vm.define "dockerhost"
  config.vm.box = "dduportal/boot2docker"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port",guest: 8080, host: 8080


  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          vb.name = "dockerhost"

  end

end
```

Comment: What Docker image does `mysql` equate to? Can you provide that Dockerfile, or a link to the image you're using on Docker Hub, please?

Comment: @ThatsNinja It is the official MySQL docker file: [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

Answer (score 2):

Solved. As I suspected the ports were not getting forwarded between the host machine and the docker host. The solution is to move the port forwarding config line:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
```

into the docker host Vagrant file. MySQL Workbench on the Windows host can then connect on localhost:3306.